# Python Exception: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

im trying to find the mistake in my code.
My IDE (Coderunner on Mac) only says this:

```
File "A3.py", line 27, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I never had this exception. I don't know how to handle it and where the problem is. What I am doing wrong?

This is my code... I commented line 27.

```
with open("spd.txt", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    text = f.read()
text = text.replace("\xad", "")

words = []
for word in text.lower().split():
    word = word.strip("‚‘!,.:«»-()'_#-–„“■;+*?") 
    if word != "":
        if not word[-1].isalnum(): 
            print(repr(word))
        words.append(word)


trigrams = {}
for i in range(len(words)-2):
       word = words[i]
       nextword = words[i + 1]
       nextnextword = words[i + 2]
       key = (word, nextword, nextnextword)
       trigrams[key] = trigrams.get(key, 0) + 1


l = list(trigrams.items())
l.sort(key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]))
l.reverse()

for key, count in trigrams: #This is line 27
    if count < 5: 
        break 
    word = key[0]
    nextword = key[1]
    nextnextword = key[2]
    print(word, nextword, nextnextword, count)
```

Comment: You need to do `for key, count in trigrams.items():`. to iterate over the keys _and_ the values together. Iterating just over the dictionary only yields the keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do `for key, count in trigrams.items():` to iterate over the keys *and* the values together. Iterating just over the dictionary only yields the keys.

Answer (score 0):

When your do

```
for key, count in trigrams:
    # do stuff
```

it is equivalent to:

```
it = iter(trigrams)
while True:
    try:
        key, count = it.__next__()
        # do stuff
    except StopIteration:
        break
```

This is what Python does behind the scenes when you iterate over an iterable. As you can see from the above code, a function call to the `__next__()` method of the `trigrams` dictionary's iterator is made when `trigrams` is iterated over. The `__next__()` function only returns the next ***key*** in the dictionary though. eg:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> iter(d).__next__()
'a'
>>>
```

So when you try to unpack the return value of `iter(trigrams).__next__()`, Python raises an error because only *one* value is returned, not two. eg:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> a, b = iter(d).__next__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
    a, b = iter(d).__next__()
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
>>>
```

To fix this, you need to use the `dict.items()` method to return a tuple which contains a key, value pair which you can then unpack. [From the documentation on `.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items):

> Return a new view of the dictionary’s items ((key, value) pairs). See the documentation of view objects.

```
for key, count in trigrams.items(): # Use the .items() method
    if count < 5: 
        break 
    word = key[0]
    nextword = key[1]
    nextnextword = key[2]
    print(word, nextword, nextnextword, count)
```